# why my rigidbody limit localeulerangles stoping on -90 and 90

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, communityengine

i constrain local y and z angles for rigidbody,
but x-axis rotation clamps at -90 and 90.
I have included "is kinematic = true" for rigidbody to check the rotation.

[enter image description [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rHMi.gif)here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Y09.jpg)

Comment: Having the range on x-axis of -90 to +90 is common (180 degrees) and you can the other 180 degrees simply by changing the sign on the y axis.